# How to know which exact .NET assembly is used

Tags: .net, fsc

I need to know exactly which FSharp.Compiler.dll file the Fsc.exe is using. I have reasons to believe that it is not using the file adjacent to it, so I want to know which one it does use. The version numbers are the same, but the locations are different.

Any ideas how to find out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could always load up [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and see which DLLs are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a reference to the compiler object, you should do the following :
`compiler.GetType().Assembly.Location()`